# How to keep paths selected with direct selection tool illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, cs6

I am having trouble selecting paths using the direct selection tool. Once I click and drag it selects some paths. I want to click and drag again to select more paths however it deselects the paths I've already selected. This is for an image I live traced so quite a lot of paths.
[image]
[image]
enter image description here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Direct Selection tool you *don't* want to click-drag over the same things twice. The first drag will select something, the second will *deselect* it.

It may be helpful to use the `Hide` function, which I often do. If something is hidden, it can't be selected/deselected. So Hide what you've already selected, make a new selection, hide that, repeat. Then show all.

- Click-drag with the Direct Selection tool to get a selection
- Then choose `Object > Hide > Selection` from the menu 
  (Quicker via shortcut...  <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>)
- Once everything you *want* as a selection is hidden, 
  choose `Object > Show All` ( <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>**Option/Alt**</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>)

Everything you've hidden will become visible **and** selected.

[image]

Note you can also use the `Lock` function rather than `Hide`. Same workflow. `Hide` can simply makes it easier to tell what has been selected and what hasn't.